# Deleting the bottom line of a file using ant

Tags: ant

I have created ant target that is supposed to delete the bottom line of a file and then echo it out to a file of a different name. The code that I'm using for the target is:

```
<loadfile srcfile="/dir/example/file.txt" property="last.line.removed">
        <filterchain>
            <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.TailFilter">
                <param name="lines" value="-1"/>
                <param name="skip" value="1"/>
            </filterreader>
        </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
<echo message="${last.line.removed}" file="/dir/example/file2.txt" append="true"/>
```

I have ran this target in the build on its own and it is just echoing back the original file rather than removing the bottom line.

If anyone could tell me why this doesn't work or a better way of doing it then it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not replicate the problem...

## Example

Running the code produces the expected result (demonstrated by the diff command):

```
$ ant
$ diff src/file.txt target/file.txt
2d1
< how are you?
```

Project files

```
├── build.xml
├── src
│   └── file.txt
└── target
    └── file.txt
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="target"/>

    <loadfile srcfile="src/file.txt" property="last.line.removed">
      <filterchain>
        <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.TailFilter">
          <param name="lines" value="-1"/>
          <param name="skip" value="1"/>
        </filterreader>
      </filterchain>
    </loadfile>

    <echo message="${last.line.removed}" file="target/file.txt" append="true"/>

  </target>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="target"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

### src/file.txt

```
hello world
how are you?
```

### target/file.txt

```
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks - Since you couldn't replicate I figured it must be something to do with the txt. Turns out I had 3 lines of white space underneath the supposed "bottom" of the file, deleted all of that and it now works as expected

Comment: @RobbieAvill yup! Why can't the computer do what you want it do and not what you ask it to do? :-)